# Is it safe from a security perspective to have the WAN and LAN on the same switch?

Tags: networking

My modem connection needs to go to a switch before it gets to a router. I do this because my ISP provides up to four public IP addresses per connection to the ISP.

In order to keep everything tidy, I’ve allocated a number of ports to access a specific VLAN on my Cisco switch. The Webif, SSH etc of the switch have all been configured to an IP within the VLAN. The other ports have been left unconfigured. Those are connected to the modem, router and a few other devices that need a public IP.

I use pfSense as my router. I’ve setup a VLAN on a dedicated interface. That interface is connected to the allocaded VLAN ports.

On every device in my LAN network (including the router), IPv6 has been disabled.

So knowing that, is my setup safe to use?

Comment: Unclear what this means: “You’ll get more IPs from the provider.” Do you mean you can get another IP address from the ISP if you plug a device directly into the switch?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes, you get up to 4 public ip addresses

Comment: Wow. Nice setup. Edited to make it clearer what the deal is since many people only get one single public IP address.

Comment: Thanks yeah I got lucky I still had an older modem, now you get those all in one modems you're always behind their router (you can't access the config panel). Until it dies, I have slower internet then I pay for but four IPs :)

Answer (score 2):

#### The simple answer to this is no, it's not a security risk.

If I understand your setup correctly, you are essentially “[routing on a stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_on_a_stick).”

As long as you don’t degrade the security in some way under the firewall interface rules by allowing inter-VLAN communication between the two VLAN s, you should be fine.

Comment: Well basically I did switchport mode access, access vlan XX on the vlan ports and left the others default/unconfigured is that how I suppose to do that? The WAN ports cannot have any tagging for reasons

Comment: I usually administratively down ports that aren't in use.

Comment: I use the unconfigured ones for the WAN connections. I was trying to say that I have one VLAN (my lan network) . I've left the WAN ports unconfigured as everything seems to work ok like this